# IIS6 Required for Sitecore

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, sitecore, sitecore6

On a development Windows Server 2008, I have had Sitecore 6.3.1 running underneath IIS7. This installation was manually installed. It has a few minor issues when using the desktop interface, but nothing that prevents me from developing and running Sitecore.

I am now in the process of installing Sitecore 6.3.1 using the Sitecore web application installer (.exe). I want to see if installing Sitecore this way resolves the errors that I had been experiencing.

When running the installation wizard, the prerequisite says that the server is not IIS6 compatible and must be installed.

Do I need to install IIS6 or can I just ignore this message and continue with the install using IIS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about ignoring it but you also don't need to install II6. You just need to install IIS 6 Management compatibility.

Go to Windows features (Programs and Features) -> Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS 6 Management Compatibility.

Comment: I installed IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility, IIS 6 WMI Compatibility, and IIS 6 Management Console as outlined in the following article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397374(v=exchg.80).aspx  I verified that it was installed but when I re-run the Sitecore app installer, I still do not pass the IIS6 Compatibility perquisite. Do you recommend continuing the install anyway?

Comment: only difference for me is that I have IIS Scripting also checked.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not quite relevant now when Sitecore 6.5.x is out, I'll give a bit detailed explanation here for those who face with the problem.

To begin with, Sitecore itself DOESN'T NEED the IIS6 compatibility feature to be enabled. It runs just fine on a pure IIS 7 from the very first version, which supports IIS 7. It is ONLY SETUP.EXE which needs this feature on.

Some technical background: Sitecore installation program is built with [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org), plus a number of custom things on top. As long as it installs an ASP.NET web application, it has to talk to IIS during the installation process (create IIS website, application pool, etc.) When Vista arrived, the WiX toolset didn't have the native support for IIS 7 (according to the people involved, it's a consequence of complex relationships with Microsoft IIS team, etc. :)).

So, the only option was to turn IIS6 compatibility ON in order to perform necessary actions from inside the installation package.

And here we come to another problem. Basically, only "IIS6 metabase compatibility" is required, but there was a bug in the Sitecore installation, which made the users to enable the entire "IIS6 compatibility" stack. This one was fixed long time ago, but, obviously the installation program is not rebuilt for the older versions.

So, to summarize:

- If you use Sitecore 6.5.x or higher, you don't have to worry about it. There's no IIS6 compatibility dependency any longer
- The "IIS6 compatibility" is required **only for setup.exe** to do its job - you can safely disable it back after Sitecore installation
- If you are out of luck and have to install that very version, just **enable the entire IIS6 compatibility feature** to be sure it passes fine

Hope it sheds more light.